# I want to see user youtube playlists after he sign-in with google to my flutter application

Tags: flutter, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-signin, google-authentication

I would love to see user's playlists (private one too) after he sign-in to my flutter app using sign-in with google method. So far my code is not working. Response looks like this: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 404, message: Channel not found)

When I try it from browser : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D

it shows popup with my youtube channels (I have many channels assign to my google account) but on mobile I dont see this popup

```dart
import 'package:extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart'
    as auth;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/people/v1.dart';
import "package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart";
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
      onPressed: _handleSignIn,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    final _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        PeopleServiceApi.contactsReadonlyScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubepartnerScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeForceSslScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeReadonlyScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeChannelMembershipsCreatorScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubepartnerChannelAuditScope,
      ],
    );
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    final httpClient = await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();
    final YouTubeApi youtubeApi = YouTubeApi((httpClient)!);

    final response = await youtubeApi.playlists.list(
      ["snippet"],
      mine: true,
      maxResults: 25,
    );
    print(response.items!.length);
    print(response.items);
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: NOPE. If you find solution please let me know this is very important for me but then it was imposible.